# I want to return an mysql query with a list of items, and a count. What's the best way to write this?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

I want to select all the videos with a specific value

I know this is how you would get the count

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos WHERE owner=1`

and this is how you would get all the videos

`SELECT * FROM videos WHERE owner=1`

but I want to do it in one query where I can return a json object with an array of videos along with a count like this

```
{
 videos: [],
 count: 0
}
```

Comment: `videos` will have a `videos.length`. Otherwise you must do something verbose like `SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos ...) FROM videos  ...`

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 5.7 has functions for [JSON_OBJECT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) and [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg), which can help in this case.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'videos', JSON_ARRAYAGG(videos.title),
  'count', COUNT(*)
) AS result
FROM videos
WHERE owner = 1
```

If you want the videos array to have objects instead of just strings, then nest a JSON_OBJECT call inside.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'videos', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'title', videos.title,
      'owner', videos.owner,
      'rating', videos.rating,
      ...other key-value pairs...
    )
  ),
  'count', COUNT(*)
) AS result
FROM videos
WHERE owner = 1
```

If you want to limit the number of rows included in the aggregation, you'd have to do it in a derived-table subquery, because aggregate functions don't have any way to do LIMIT.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(...same as above...) AS result
FROM (
    SELECT title, owner, rating
    FROM videos
    WHERE owner = 1
    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
) AS t
```

Comment: I agree — I understood the question to be about producing JSON, not reading JSON. The functions `JSON_OBJECT()` and `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` produce JSON.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I am out of touch.

Comment: What would that look like if I wanted to add a limit on there. 

For example
LIMIT 0, 20

Comment: I added an example in the answer above.